# Jenkins- accessing from outside a test box

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, remote-desktop

I have jenkins on a test box #1.  I am able to access jenkins from outside the test box without remoting in by going to http://testbox1.site.local:8080

I am unable to do this for text box #2.  The only difference is apache tom cat is also installed, along with jenkins, on test box #2.

Does anyone have any ideas why http://testbox2.site.local:8080 won't work?

Comment: What does netstat show is listening on port 8080 on testbox2 ?

Comment: MT, thanks for the quick response.  After running netstat on testbox1 and testbox2, 8080 did not appear in either results.

Comment: try `netstat -ano` to see all ports in numeric form with the owning process. -a is crucial to see ports used by server processes.

Comment: testbox#1
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       36560
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       36560


testbox#2
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2272

Comment: Check for firewall and   Anti virus software

Comment: When I turned the firewall off, it worked.  Thanks! I imagine I do not want to turn the firewall off permanently- can someone walk me through how to keep the firewall on but allow  http://testbox2.site.local:8080 to be reached?